# choosing indices in tensor notation

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, tensors

I have the following operator, where $\rho$ is a scalar and $u$ is a vector:
$$
\nabla (\rho u) - (\nabla \rho)u - u(\nabla \rho)
$$
My book writes this in index notation as
$$
\partial_\alpha(\rho u_\beta) - u_\beta\partial_\alpha\rho-u_\alpha\partial_\beta\rho
$$
**My question is**, why does the book use the indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$ again for the second and third term? Shouldn't they have their own set of indices?

Comment: Is the nabla a gradient or a divergence? Notation seems to indicate gradient, so you are computing the Jacobi matrix of $ρu$. If so, then the original difference is a difference of three matrices that you now compute elementwise, you are taking the same elements with the same indices from all three matrices.

Comment: If what you say is true, then you would've got 6th order tensor.

Comment: @Lutzl It is the gradient. My question is much more simple than that, why not use three different pairs of indices, one for each term?

Comment: Because you subtract matrices by subtracting terms at the same position. The formula is for column $α$ and row $β$, located as in the ordinary Jacobian $$\begin{bmatrix}\partial_1f_1&\dots&\partial_nf_1\\\vdots&&\vdots\\\partial_1f_m&\dots&\partial_nf_m\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

What you are really doing when introducing indices is replacing $\nabla$ by $e_α\partial_α$ (using Einstein summation) and $u$ by $u_βe_β$, $e_α$ being the canonical basis vectors. Then

$$∇(ρu)=∂_α(ρu_β)\cdot e_α\otimes e_β$$

and in the full expression you combine the coefficients of the same basis vector $e_α⊗e_β$ of the tensor product in all three terms.